# Using Raphael.js in Confluence! Workaround for the conflict?

Tags: raphael, confluence

I want to use Raphael.js in my Confluence pages. However, when it's injected into a page it's (by html ) it is breaking up Confluence's Raphael segment, ie. page tree is not displayed etc. I dig up a little browser console inspection and with confluence directory and found-out that raphael.spinner is the only instance.

What would be a work-around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the dirtiest way I think :
I modified Raphael.js with all the occurences of Raphael with RaphaelModified. (Then I also have to to replace the Raphael entires within my other libraries depending to Raphael, to RaphaelModified).
When I  injected them into my pages with  it worked.
I would appreciate more permanent and elegant way though..